# Unable to get $_FILES

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, slim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why files don’t get uploaded with this HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035922/why-files-dont-get-uploaded-with-this-html-php)

i'm using Slim Framework to make a REST web service to do a simple service:

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

$app = new Slim();
$app->get('/update','showUpdatePage');
$app->post('/update','store');
$app->run();

function store(){
    print_r($_FILES);
}
function showUpdatePage(){
    echo <<<EOT
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2 style="text-align:center;">Load new file</h2>
            <div style="width:40%;margin:0 auto;">
                <form method="post" action="update">
                    <input type="file" name="theFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
                    <input type="submit" value="load"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
EOT;
}
```

My problem is that the line

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

give me empty array.. how can i fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### enctype="multipart/form-data"

This [isn't an attribute of an input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) - [it's a form attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype). As such your form is not setup to submit files, and the enctype attribute of the input will simply be ignored.

#### Valid Example

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="update">
    <input type="file" name="theFile">
    <input type="submit" value="load"/>
</form>
```

Comment: .. :) great man! i had not really noticed it.. all fixed! :)